# Array.foreach only gets val() from the last input id with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, keyup

Please help me figure out why only the last input id gets its value added to the input id= #attr3 with keyup.

I need both inputs in the div to have their values put into the input outside the div separated with a comma(,). i made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dc6v6gjd/1/. Thanks

```
<div id ="candy">
   <input type="text" id="attr1" name="emailAddress" value="">
   <input type="text" id="attr2" name="emailAddress" value="">
</div>
   <input type="text" id="attr3" name="username" value="">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var text = $("#candy :input").map(function () {
              return this.id; 
                        }).get();        
        var attr = [];

        for (i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
                attr.push('#'+ text[i]);
                }
        var mat = attr.join(", ");

    $(mat).keyup(function(){
         update();

    function update() {
        attr.forEach(function(index, i){
        // alert(i);
           $("#attr3").val( $(attr[i]).val() + "," );           

        });
      }      
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you're overriding the value of `attr3` on each iteration of forEach. You could instead use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the value.

e.g.

```
function update() {
  var val = attr
    .map(function(a) { 
      return $(a).val(); 
    })
   .join(",");

   $("#attr3").val(val);
}
```

That being said I'd probably go with a simpler solution like this.

```js
// set the keyup event handler and add all inputs to an array.
var inputs = $("#candy :input").keyup(function() {
  update();
}).get();

// read all input values into comma separated string and update attr3
function update() {
  var val = inputs.map(function(i) {
    return $(i).val();
  }).join(",");
  
  $("#attr3").val(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="candy">
  <input type="text" id="attr1" name="emailAddress" value="">
  <input type="text" id="attr2" name="emailAddress" value="">
</div>
<input type="text" id="attr3" name="username" value="">
```

**Update:** Support dynamically added inputs.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#candy :input", function() {
  update();
});

function update() {
  var val = $("#candy :input").get().map(function(i) {
    return $(i).val();
  }).join(",");

  $("#attrFinal").val(val);
}

var count = 3;
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#candy").append("<input type='text' id='attr" + count++ + "' name='emailAddress' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="candy">
  <input type="text" id="attr1" name="emailAddress" value="">
  <input type="text" id="attr2" name="emailAddress" value="">
</div>
<input type="text" id="attrFinal" name="username" value="">

<button id="add">Add New</button>
```

Comment: Please H77, how do i get this code to work with dynamically generated input fields

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate.